# Is it possible to create a symbolic link between tables in one database to tables in another?

Tags: mysql

As the title states, I'm wondering if it's possible to selectively choose tables that symbolically link to another database.  Ideally when either database has a table that is linked and is written to the same data will be written to the identical table in the other database.  Ultimately I have only one column in one table that I don't want linked.

If it matters this is concerning XBMC and wanting profiles to share a database but not the watched status.

And maybe I'm asking the question wrong, what I want to do is symbolically link almost everything in one database to another database; I want everything but one column in one table linked.

Comment: Yep, your after a view to a different table  see [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)  BUT ONLY If it resides on the same server see [this article](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,89791,90182)  or it can all be done with a federated database (See 2nd link last response and articles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple: You need Triggers for insert and update on those tables you wish to replicate. This will also solve your "all but one column" problem.